# How to display specific row data in dialog box using Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Below I have written on for the open dialog method in the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';

import { ModalService } from '../_modal';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-customer',
  templateUrl: './ViewCustomer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ViewCustomer.component.css']
})
export class ViewCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
bookings: any;
bodyText: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private http: HttpClient, private alertify: AlertifyService
    ,         private modalService: ModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Bookings();
    console.log(this.Bookings());
    this.bodyText = 'This text can be updated in modal 1';
  }

  openModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.open(id);
}

closeModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.close(id);
}


  Bookings() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/Book/').subscribe(response => {
      this.bookings = response;
      console.log(this.bookings);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

}
```

Below I've included the template.
I'm trying to make the first button show the first data displayed the second button displaying the second data.
Currently, I have the dialog displaying all the data whenever the user clicks on both of the buttons.

> 

```
<h1>List of reservations</h1>
<div>
  <p *ngFor= "let booking of bookings">
    {{booking.customers.firstName}},
    {{booking.id}}, {{booking.date}},
    {{booking.id}},{{booking.tableNumber}}
    {{booking.id}},{{booking.additionalInfo}}
   
  </p>
  <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-2')">Open Modal 2</button>
  <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-3')">Open Modal 3</button>
</div>



<p>
  
</p>

<div>
  <p>{{bodyText}}</p>
  <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-1')">Open Modal 1</button>
  <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-2')">Open Modal 2</button>
</div>

<jw-modal id="custom-modal-1">
  <h1>A Custom Modal!</h1>
  <p>Home page text: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bodyText" /></p>
  <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>

<jw-modal id="custom-modal-2">
  <h1 style="height:100px">A Tall Custom Modal!</h1>
  <p *ngFor= "let booking of bookings">
  
    {{booking.id}}, {{booking.date}},
    {{booking.id}},{{booking.tableNumber}}
    {{booking.id}},{{booking.additionalInfo}}
</p>
  <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-2');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>



<jw-modal id="custom-modal-3">
  <h1 style="height:100px">second one hhaha</h1>
  <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-3');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>



<!-- <p *ngFor= "let customers of bookings ">
  {{booking.id}}, {{bookings.firstName}}


  
  
  {{booking.customerId}}, {{booking.FirstName}}
</p>


<p>hello</p> -->

<p>{{ bookings[0]?.customers[0]?.Color?.Name }}</p>
```

> ***what do I need to change below in the modal service?***

> 

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ModalService {
private modals: any[] = [];
selectedBooking: any;
bookings: any;


add(modal: any) {
    // add modal to array of active modals
    this.modals.push(modal);
}

remove(id: string) {
    // remove modal from array of active modals
    this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
}

open(id: string) {
    // open modal specified by id
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === id);
    modal.open();
}

close(id: string) {
    // close modal specified by id
    const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === id);
    modal.close();
}
```

}

> 

if you look at the image it shows that whenver i click on open modal button 2 it should only show emma's detail in the dialog box but it shows Tommy's details with Emma's detail.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGusM.png)

[iamge 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X91hb.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are showing all the records in the modal. Here you are looping through all of them (`bookings`) in displaying them:

```
<jw-modal id="custom-modal-2">
  <h1 style="height:100px">A Tall Custom Modal!</h1>
  <p *ngFor= "let booking of bookings">
  
    {{booking.id}}, {{booking.date}},
    {{booking.id}},{{booking.tableNumber}}
    {{booking.id}},{{booking.additionalInfo}}
</p>
  <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-2');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>
```

If `ModalService` is something you created in your project (I mean not from a node module) then you can declare a variable there, set that when the button is clicked and use it in the modal. Something like,

```
export class ModalService {
selectedBooking: any;
.
.
}
```

**Component HTML**

```
  <button (click)="openModal(booking)">Open Modal</button>
```

**Component TS**

```
openModal(booking: any) {
this.modalService.selectedBooking = booking;
    this.modalService.open();
}
```

**Modal HTML**

```
<jw-modal id="custom-modal-2">
  <h1 style="height:100px">A Tall Custom Modal!</h1>
    {{selectedBooking.id}}, {{selectedBooking.date}},
    {{selectedBooking.id}},{{selectedBooking.tableNumber}}
    {{selectedBooking.id}},{{selectedBooking.additionalInfo}}
</p>
  <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-2');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the post above which shows the modal.service. what do I need to change from there?

Comment: Is there a reason you are looping through all the bookings in the modal?
 `<p *ngFor= "let booking of bookings">`

Comment: Not really but I just the dialog box to display a single record. I don't need to loop through all of the bookings.

Comment: if there were several records of data displayed on the webpage and each of the records has each button. These buttons allow the user to view more details in a dialog box. This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: See if you can create a stackblitz then I can try to make it work.

Comment: Sorry it took 2 months to reply back but I have figured it out thank you